Remedy for non-compliance with a license
Tools like blackbox and fossa advertise being able to find non-compliance but I couldn't find detailed advice on what to do if a non-compliance is found.
Suppose a company discovers that it has used source code or other materials under a license it has not complied with. What steps should it take to rectify the situation?
Is it sufficient for the company to remove the copyrighted code from future versions and cease distribution of non-compliant software, similar to the effect of a "take down" notice?
What further actions might be necessary?
Regarding the existence of copyrighted material in the project's source repository? Should it be scrubbed from version control altogether?
Of course any company should consult its legal team in such cases but could there potential legal ramifications or obligations for the company due to retrospective violations of licenses?

I guess I'm asking what should go into a compliance policy outlining how a responsible company should handle such situations which would need to be written by a legal team.
The closest I've found is https://schjodt.com/news/open-source-policies-why-and-how
The advice will of course vary depending on the licenses involved. Attribution licenses are easy so for the sake of argument assume something like the GPL.

It is not really possible to give an answer, because a lot depends on how deeply the non-compliant code is embedded within your product by the time you discover that it is non-compliant. It makes a very big difference if you find that a minor dependency was added in a non-compliant way in the last few weeks, or that the core of your product has been non-compliant for the last decade.

@BartvanIngenSchenau: On top of that, in a commercial situation like this, the only correct answer is "ask your in-house lawyer(s), or retain a lawyer if you don't have one already." Anything else is just playing Russian roulette with your business. Statutory damages for this sort of thing can potentially be huge.

I am thinking about policy here. I don't have a specific example in mind. I've seen this kind of thing happen on open source projects using other open source projects for some relatively easily replaced functionality and the remedy is simply to remove the code going forward. Its likely neither has a legal team in that case.

Does your development team/department have a formal policy on what kind of open source is allowed and how this must be done? If the answer is 'no' then this should be fixed. You need to make it clear to everyone what is allowed and what is not, and what should be done in each case (e.g. where to attach license noties, getting product manager approval, etc.,)

I have seen several policies of this sort at various companies but note that the remedy section is typically limited to "involve the legal team".


could there potential legal ramifications [...] for the company due to retrospective violations of licenses?

Absolutely. The company distributed material in violation of copyright, and the copyright holders then have the ability to sue for the damage caused. Nothing they do in the future can undo that harm, and if necessary a court will decide on the size of that harm. In practice, most open source copyright holders are happy to "forgive and forget", sometimes after a charitable donation or similar from the offending company, but their right in law still exists should they wish to enforce it.

I'm answering to your title: What remedies are available if an open source license is violated? This is a general answer to your question, not a legal advice toward your specific circumstances.
In the US, here is an incomplete list of possible remedy. Links to examples are mostly outside of the context of open source due to its scarcity, but they would help understand the meaning.
Contract Remedies
An open source license itself is also a contract between the licensor and licensee. Violating the license also implies breaching the contract. Therefore, remedies under a contract theory may be available and adequate. Remedies include

expectation damages:  (Examples)

put the non-breaching party in as good of a position as if the breaching party fully performed their contractual duties.


restitution: (Examples)

A remedy associated with unjust enrichment in which the amount of recovery is typically based on the defendant's gain rather than the plaintiff's loss.


specific performance: (Examples)

The court orders a party to actually perform its promise as closely as possible, because monetary damages are somehow inadequate to fix the harm.

Since contract is typically governed by state law, details may be different across states.


Copyright Remedies
If it is deemed that copyright infringement exists, Federal law offers remedies specific to copyright infringement.

Actual damages and profits:

The copyright owner is entitled to recover the actual damages suffered by him or her as a result of the infringement, and any profits of the infringer that are attributable to the infringement and are not taken into account in computing the actual damages... 17 U.S. Code § 504(b)


Statutory damages: 17 U.S. Code § 504(c) Roughly monetary award based on the circumstances. The code section contains detailed explanations.

Other Remedies
Other types of remedies may also be relevant, such as those arise from patent infringement or trademark infringement.
A Side Note on Permissive Licenses that Require Attributions
You said:

Attribution licenses are easy so for the sake of argument assume something like the GPL.

While a permissive license that only requires attribution is easier than the GPL to comply, meaningful remedies may be still available upon violation. For example, check out the statutory damages under the "Copyright Remedies" above:

the copyright owner may elect, at any time before final judgment is rendered, to recover, instead of actual damages and profits, an award of statutory damages for all infringements involved in the action, with respect to any one work, for which any one infringer is liable individually, or for which any two or more infringers are liable jointly and severally, in a sum of not less than $750 or more than $30,000 as the court considers just. 17 U.S. Code § 504(c)(1)

17 U.S. Code § 504(c)(2) permits a higher monetary award in more extreme circumstances.
